# Drupal theme for specific taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hi am new to theming of Drupal 6 what I want is let say am on http://abc.com and the theme is Garland now what I want is when I go to http://abc.com/me/mypage the theme of this page should be different from previous. In other words:

I have two pages say node/12321 and node/1231 I want to apply custom theme on them but not the Garland theme how can I remove all the style sheet of garland theme and add my custom style sheets to it without modifyng to page-node-xxxx.tpl.php page I have make a search on it it says some preprocessing page which am unable to understand.

Plus, how can I apply theme to page with specific taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.  It allows you to change the theme depending on the path, taxonomy, and more.  From the ThemeKey project page:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple
>   or sophisticated theme-switching rules
>   which allow automatic selection of a
>   theme depending on **current path**,
>   **taxonomy terms**, language, node-type,
>   and many, many other properties. It
>   can also be easily extended to support
>   additional properties exposed by other
>   modules. In combination with Drupal's
>   theme inheritance and ThemeKey
>   Properties you can easily achieve
>   features like:
>
> - individually-styled channels a
> - front-page / "splash" screen a
> - date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different
> - auto-detected mobile devices special
> - themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific
> - themes indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … ) testing
>     your redesign safely on a live server
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following modules
1)[ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey)
2)[Page Theme](http://drupal.org/project/page_theme)
3) Sections

Go any one of above which is suitable for your implementation.

Thanks
RT